# Navigation bar layout margins in ios 13 with xcode 11.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

How can I reduce the margins of left and right of navigation bar in ios 13.[image]

when we set layout margins to subviews of navigation bar it crashed the app. But below mentioned code is working fine in ios 12 with xcode 10.3.

***subclass of navigation bar***

```
for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
    view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8);
}
```

Comment: do you want to remove padding from right side of the cart icon?

Comment: yes, right side of cart icon and left side of logo

Comment: and these are bar button items? If yes then check by setting the background color of that button. You can create your custom bar button using any `UIView` sub-class like UIButton! And you can set content alignment in the button. In short, create a bar button using the normal button(having content left aligned or right)!